# Ubuntu 20.04 install fails on Sony Vaio VPCEL1E1E

Tags: boot, 20.04, vaio, sony

A couple of months ago I was given an old laptop. A **Sony VAIO - VPCEL1E1E**. I upgraded to Windows 10 and finally I decided to install Ubuntu as soon as the latest version **20.04 LTS** was released. Let me start by saying that I am not new to the GNU/Linux world because I have been using it since 2008. My first choice was Ubuntu Studio since I deal with 3D graphics and also being a musician. So I downloaded the ISO and burned it as usual. Using this old laptop, the first problem immediately arises. After burning the ISO and reinserting the DVD into the player, it is not recognized. Then I downloaded the same ISO again with another Laptop that has already installed Ubuntu 19.04 and I proceeded again to create the DVD that I need for installation on the Sony VAIO. Again, the old laptop player does not recognize the DVD. I think of a problem with Windows 10 and still decide to proceed with the installation. I enter the legacy BIOS of Insyde Corp. R0130E3 and set the DVD player as the first boot disk as usual. Installation does not start. Black screen for an hour. So I decide to download other versions of Ubuntu, Mate, LXDE and Kubuntu from the working Ubuntu laptop and burned all of them. Even in these cases the installation does not start. I also tried to do an installation using a USB flash drive. Nothing in this case too. Installation does not start. Will I be forced to use Windows 10 forever on this one or is there a solution to this?

Comment: Did you tried to boot other USB or CD/DVD installation/live disks from this VAIO? Can you get any info about this process from previous owner?

Comment: After many attempts the DVD RW Unit don't recognize any Debian based GNU/Linux distro. I tried an old Fedora 4 and it was recognized from Win10

Comment: Looks more like as hardware issue. But theoretically you can move harddisk drive from this laptop to other laptop or desktop to install system. Then move disk back to laptop.

Comment: As you say it could be a hardware problem. But at this point I doubt it. Explain to me why the DVD player works with other distros. I have recently tried a CD with Gparted live and it starts correctly and I can also access the NTFS partitions of the drive. I have tried an old Debian CD and it works. I have tried an old DVD with Fedora 4 and it works. Your solution to replace the two hardisks doesn't make any sense since they are two completely different computers. Doing as you say I risk ruining the computer that works.